# Animate objects using jQuery. How can I used three techniques, fadeIn, animate and fadeOut in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is my HTML CODE:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var img = $('#img');
  $("#start").click(function() {
    img.fadeIn(1000, function() {
      img.animate({
        left: $(window).width() - 400
      }, 3000, function() {
        img.animate({
          left: '0px'
        }, 3000, function() {
          img.fadeOut(1000);
        })
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.img {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  /* background-color: red; */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="start">Start</button>
<div>
  <img id="img" src="guy-walking.gif" width="400" />
</div>
```

How can I turn the guy(the gif) around so he walks back across the screen forward? When the guy is moving back to the starting point, i.e. right to left, it will look like he is Moon Walking backward. And I can't turn him around and have him walk back forwards. Please help!!!

Comment: Share your HTML code

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS' `scaleX` property to flip an image.

```
transform: scaleX(-1);
```

In the example below, I created a class called "back" and I simply add the class when the animation needs to be flipped.

Keep in mind that in my example, my gif animation was walking from right to left. That's why I flipped the image from start and "unflip" it when it reaches the right. You'll have to swap the scaleX properties if your animation is from left to right.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var img = $('#img');
  $("#start").click(function() {
    img.fadeIn(1000, function() {
      img.animate({
        left: $(window).width() - 400
      }, 3000, function() {
       img.addClass('back');
        img.animate({
          left: '0px'
        }, 3000, function() {
          img.fadeOut(1000);
        })
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#img {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}

#img.back {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="start">Start</button>
<div >
  <img id="img" src="https://media0.giphy.com/media/XGnWMiVXL87Xa/source.gif" width="400" />
</div>
```

Comment: Love this answer!